# Header Image Panning with CSS - Firefox not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, animation, css-animations

I have implemented a panning animation on my header image on the following webpage, which works great on Safari & Chrome. I am having problems getting it to work on firefox, i have tried playing with -moz- and -webkit- properties but nothing seems to be making much change.

http://osealeisure.com/wordpress/osea/about/

CSS

```
    @keyframes panning {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
  }
   50% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
  200% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes panning {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
  }
   50% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
  200% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes panning {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
  }
   50% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
  200% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

.vc_custom_1487756740420 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%!important;
  animation: panning 40s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: panning 40s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: panning 40s infinite linear;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the Mozilla animation syntax:

```
-moz-animation: panning 40s infinite linear;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That was what i was assuming however i am not seeing it working in Firefox with that line added. The image is still static. Do i need to include anything else?